# DataGridView Copy Paste Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

I was wondering if someone could help me. I have wrote some some code that will copy from the Clipboard into a DatagridView. The issue that I am having is that everything works as it is suppose to except the first cell.

For Example if I copy from Excel 2 columns only one row the value of 20 in the first column and the value of 30 in the second column

Then when I paste it in the DataGridView I get the following.

In the first column I get the number 20 and then a large space and the the value of 30 but in the second column only the value of 30 shows up.

Below is my code id anyone has an idea on how to fix that first cell please help me

```
 if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            char[] rowSplitter = { '\r', '\n' };
            char[] columnSplitter = { '\t' };
            //get the text from clipboard
            IDataObject dataInClipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            string stringInClipboard = (string)dataInClipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
            //split it into lines
            string[] rowsInClipboard = stringInClipboard.Split(rowSplitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            //get the row and column of selected cell in grid
            int r = DGV.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            int c = DGV.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;
            //add rows into grid to fit clipboard lines
            if (DGV.Rows.Count < (r + rowsInClipboard.Length))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PasteValues Will be Outside of Grid");
                return;
            }
            // loop through the lines, split them into cells and place the values in the corresponding cell.
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rowsInClipboard.Length; iRow++)
            {
                //split row into cell values
                string[] valuesInRow = rowsInClipboard[iRow].Split(columnSplitter);
                //cycle through cell values
                for (int iCol = 0; iCol < valuesInRow.Length; iCol++)
                {
                    //assign cell value, only if it within columns of the grid
                    if (DGV.ColumnCount - 1 >= c + iCol)
                    {
                        DGV.Rows[r + iRow].Cells[c + iCol].Value = valuesInRow[iCol];
                        for (int i = 0;
                        i < selectedCellCount; i++)
                        {
                            DGV.SelectedCells[i].Value = valuesInRow[iCol]; ;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I will also add that this happens when I use the Control/Shift key selection

Comment: The Issue seems to be that it paste the Data in there first and then after that I cant overwrite it but it will overwrite any of the other cells